# Add lines from file as dictionary to list Python

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

Im trying to import a file which contains lines like this:

```
 { "dictitem" : 1, "anotherdictitem" : 2 }
```

I want to import them in to a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{ "dictitem" : "henry", "anotherdictitem" : 2 },{ "dictitem" : "peter", "anotherdictitem" : 4 },{ "dictitem" : "anna", "anotherdictitem" : 6 }]
```

I tried this: `tweetlist = open("sample.out").readlines()`

But then they get appended as a string. Does anyone have an idea? 
Thanks!

Comment: You need to decode each line using `json`

Comment: Please provide a more complete example of the source file. I seriously doubt all the lines in the file look exactly like the one shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode each line using `json`. Example:

```
import json

list = []
with open("data.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        dict = json.loads(line)
        list.append(dict)

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AST library's `literal_eval` function on each line by using a list comprehension like this:

```
import ast
tweetlist = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in open("sample.out").readlines()]
```

`ast.literal_eval` is a safer version of the `eval` function that doesn't execute functions.

Comment: I get this error:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f9c7cc4ba58>